# jQueryUI sortable (with connected lists), draggable and droppable - issues with them all working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have three elements: `#a`, `#b` and `#c`.

`#a` and `#b` are main elements that I use the sortable function with in order to swap items from one element to the other.

```
$( "#a" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "#b",
});

$( "#b" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "#a",
});
```

However, I also want to be able to drag/drop an element from `#a` to `#c`, but not from `#b` to `#c`. I am running into an issue where my code is allowing me to drag any item from `#b` to `#c`. Here is my drag/drop code:

```
$( "#a" ).draggable();
$( "#c" ).droppable();
```

Any ideas how I can stop the `#b` element from allowing its elements to be dragged/dropped to `#c`?

Comment: I put together a small example in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/3ng94wox/

Comment: I am still stuck on this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle. Here is the working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/p144dr3r/)

Updated code

JS:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#a, #b, #c" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  });

  //$( "#a" ).draggable();
  $( "#c" ).droppable({
    accept: ".acceptable",
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
                $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass("item").addClass("item-container"));
          dropped.remove();
      }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="a" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="acceptable">Item 1 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 2 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 3 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 4 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 5 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 6 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 7 (acceptable)</li>
  <li class="acceptable">Item 8 (acceptable)</li>
</ul>

<ul id="b" class="connectedSortable">
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>

Only (acceptable) items are droppable here
<ul id="c">
</ul>
```